# Oracle - Trigger BEFORE INSERT not checking constraints

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I have this table that describe the loans of books in some sort of library :

```
create table emprunt (
    num_ab number(6,0) REFERENCES abonne(numero),
    num_ex number (4,0) REFERENCES exemplaire(numero),
    d_emprunt date,
    d_retour date,
    d_ret_reel date,
    nb_relance number(1,0) CHECK (nb_relance IN (1,2,3)),
    CONSTRAINT pk_emprunt PRIMARY KEY (num_ab, num_ex, d_emprunt)
);
```

and I want to make a trigger that, when you insert a new loan, set the date of the loan as today, and the return date at today + 21 days. There is the code, that works :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER on_insert_emprunt
BEFORE INSERT ON emprunt
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    :NEW.d_emprunt := SYSDATE;
    :NEW.d_retour := SYSDATE + 21;
END;
/
```

BUT, the problem is that the primary constraint on the table emprunt is no longer checked... for exemple, if I do **several times** :

```
INSERT INTO emprunt VALUES (921102,1010,TO_DATE('29-04-2014','DD-MM-YYYY'),TO_DATE('29-04-2014','DD-MM-YYYY'),NULL,NULL);
```

It works perfectly... instead of saying me :

> UNIQUE CONSTRAINT violated

I have multiple same rows in the table...

PS : sorry for the table in french.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SYSDATE`, like all Oracle dates, has a time component. Your repeated inserts are getting different times from the trigger, and you won't see a constraint violation unless you happen to do two inserts within a second of each other. The dates are different (down to time level), and so the values used for the primary key are different - hence no constraint violation.

You can see that the primary keys are different by querying:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(d_emprunt, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS d_emprunt,
  TO_CHAR(d_retour, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS d_retour
FROM emprunt
WHERE num_ab = 921102
AND num_ex = 1010;

D_EMPRUNT           D_RETOUR          
------------------- -------------------
2015-04-29 10:55:30 2015-05-20 10:55:30
2015-04-29 10:55:35 2015-05-20 10:55:35
```

You'll see the time varies for all the records you inserted.

If you want to set the dates to midnight [you can truncate them](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions220.htm), which by default resets the time components to zero:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER on_insert_emprunt
BEFORE INSERT ON emprunt
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    :NEW.d_emprunt := TRUNC(SYSDATE);
    :NEW.d_retour := TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 21;
END;
/
```

Incidentally, your primary key doesn't look very effective. If the intention is to stop the same book being lent out twice at the same time, it's not quite doing that. It's stopping that book being lent out on the same day, but not for overlapping periods. So if I took the same book out tomorrow, the primary key value would still be unique, but the ranges would overlap.

Answer (score 0):

primary key checks

```
 (num_ab, num_ex, d_emprunt)
```

as a whole unique.

when you insert the data `num_ab and num_ex` as same but `d_emprunt` is `sysdate`.
it is changing.

If you insert twice the data within 1 sec you will get the error.